# loop using while with a multidimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

i'm trying to make a while in my multidimensional array like this:

```
$address = array();
while(!$res->EOF)
{
    $dataFromDB = array($res->fields['CODCLI'] => 
                     array(
                           "Address" => $res->fields['CIDCLI'].",".$res->fields['SIGUFS'].", USA", 
                           "Name"    => "SOMENAME")
                          );
    $address[]  = $dataFromDB;
    $res->MoveNext();
}
```

and the result is this:

```
Array
 (
   [0] => Array
      (
        [28947] => Array
            (
                [Address] => PIRIPIRI,PI,USA
                [Name] => SOMENAME
            )
      )
 )
```

but what i realy need is to come like this:

```
Array
(
  [1] => Array
    (
        [Address] => PIRIPIRI,PI,USA
        [Name] => SOMENAME
    )
)
```

i try some other stuffs, but nothing help me, what i'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove that 1st step, just do this:

```
$address[]  = array(
   "Address" => $res->fields['CIDCLI'].",".$res->fields['SIGUFS'].", USA", 
   "Name"    => "SOMENAME"
);
```

Comment: actually the `codcli` have a value my mistake on posting